# Tracing a non-concentric circle in cylindrical coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems

[image]I am trying to trace the outline of the circle, at a distance d and with radius r, with the variables rho and phi_max as defined on the diagram.

I tried to convert both coordinate systems to Cartesian and tried to solve for rho and phi_max with the Cartesian equation for the circle with the same origin. $(x-d)^2 + y^2 = r^2 .$

I converted the coordinates as:

$$
\rho \cos(\phi_{max}(\rho)) = x \\
\rho \sin(\phi_{max}(\rho)) = \pm y
$$
ignoring signs because they'll be squared anyway.

I plug these into the circle equation to get:

$$
\rho^2 - 2d\rho\cos(\phi_{max}(\rho)) + (d^2 - r^2) =0 .
$$

I can't solve this equation, it appears that there are 2 variables but only 1 equation to solve for them. I could express $\cos(\phi_{max}(\rho))$ in terms of $\rho$, then use the fact that $\rho$ is bounded ( $[d-r,d+r]$) to solve for each value of $\rho$ and $\arccos(\cos(\phi_{max}(\rho)))$, giving me the sets of values.

However, I am not sure if this would be correct, and more importantly I am concerned that I am missing an easier and more rigorous method.

Note: I am not looking for a singular angle at which the line would be tangent to the circle. $\phi_{max}$ is a function of $\rho$, described at every line that connects to a point on the circle. $\phi_{max}$ is not a maximal angle, it is the name of the variable that I did not change in a different context. Please see the additional image.
[Image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnBw8.png)

Comment: This is not a question about physics and would be better received on Mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you're missing is the distinction between the bounding $\varphi_{\text{max}}$ and the dynamical graphing variables $\rho,\varphi$. You presumably want to get an equation for a function $\rho(\varphi)$ (which really has to be a pair of functions) and you have a good starting point,$$
\rho^2-2\rho d\cos\varphi +d^2 -r^2 = 0
$$(you have an unnecessary extra square, and you are unnecessarily only looking for the maximums).

Instead, by completing the square, we get
$$
(\rho - d\cos\varphi)^2 - (d\cos \varphi)^2 +d^2 -r^2 = 0,\\
\rho(\varphi) = d\cos\varphi\pm \sqrt{r^2 - (d\sin\varphi)^2}
$$the two functions come from $\pm$ and the domain of applicability is clearly where the argument of the square root is nonnegative, $-r/d<\sin\varphi<r/d,$ so $\varphi_{\text{max}}=\sin^{-1}(r/d)$, except that there is no maximum angle if $r>d$.

Comment: I think this means that I still have one equation that relates rho and phi_max (or phi, as you called it), completing to square is more helpful and domain is clearer in this expression. Thank you.
p.s. I really shouldn't have named my variable phi_max when it wasn't a maximum, and definitely shouldn't have drawn it that way...

Answer (score 0):

At the maximal angle $\phi_{max}$ the line "rho" is tangent to the circle.
Therefore, by the Pythagorean theorem
$$
d^2=r^2+\rho^2.
$$
This can easily be solved for $\rho$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand. This seems true for a singular maximal angle, but I am looking to trace the entire circle with 'vectors' with varying lengths $\rho$ and varying angles, each of them are called $\phi_{max}$.  I see that the labeling $\phi_{max}$ must have misled people reading the question.